# solve $x^{15} \equiv 2\pmod {47}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

solve $x^{15} \equiv 2\pmod {47}$

on the solution set:

suppose that $\overline{x^{15}} = \overline{2}$ then $\overline{x^{15m}} = \overline{2^m}$

solve $15m \equiv 1 \pmod {46}\;$, gaining a solution of $m = 43$ so $15m = 46k + 1$

so $\overline{x^{15m}} = \overline{x^{46k+1}} = \overline{x} = \overline{2^{43}} = 6$

my query is that isn't $15m = 46k +1$ only in modulus 46? (as thats what we solved), how can we just plug $\overline{x^{46k+1}}$ in when we're working in modulus 47?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem says $x^{46}\equiv1\pmod{47}$

Comment: Discrete Logarithm might help you out.

Comment: thank you I understand that, but how can we plug in $15m = 46k + 1$ when we got that in modulus 46, then go into modulus 47?

Comment: What do you mean by $15m=46+1$ is only modulo $46?$ It is an actual equation!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a little simpler in this case:

Working modulo $\;47\;$ all through:

$$x^{15}=2\implies x^{45}=8$$

But Fermat's Little Theorem gives $\;x^{46}=1\;$ , so

$$x^{45}=x^{-1}x^{46}=x^{-1}\implies x^{-1}=8\implies x=8^{-1}=6$$

Comment: Not simpler. Rather, it's  *equivalent*. You use $\ 3(15)\equiv -1\pmod{46},\,$ i.e. you use $\,m = 15^{-1}\equiv -3\,$ precisely as OP does.

Comment: I don't agree, @BillDubuque. Of course, in such an elementary exercise most approaches will be equivalent to each other or close to, but I think it's way simpler to deal *directly*, in the above way, with $\;8^{-1}\pmod {47}\;$ than with what the OP did. A matter of opinions, I suppose.

Comment: You are also solving it essentially by inverting $15$ (even though you don't explicitly say so). Your method amounts to using the least magnitude rep  $\,1/15 \equiv -3\,$ vs. $\,1/15 \equiv 43\pmod{46}.\,$ So powering $\,x^{15}\equiv 2\pmod{47}\,$ to power $\,1/15\equiv -3\pmod{46}\,$ gives  $\,x\equiv 2^{-3}\equiv 1/8\equiv 48/8\equiv 6\pmod{47}$ That's how it is equivalent. Your method is simply a slightly more roundabout way of doing that.

Comment: I'd say my method is simpler *to actually carry on* than others', either by the way it is written or by the order of operations, etc. Some people seem to agree with that.

Comment: You did not explicitly give any *general* "method". But, as I showed, it can be viewed as the same general method that the OP is using. If you had some other general (i.e. non-ad-hoc) method in mind then what is it?

Comment: No "general" method I gave, @BillDubuque, and that's why I explicitly wrote "in this case". I only showed what I call "the method of playing around modulo whatever" to reach the solution. I don't understand why you insist so much on this little thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ 15m = 1\!+\!46k\,\Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\ 47\!:\ x^{15m} \equiv x^{1+46k}\equiv x(\color{#c00}{x^{46}})^k \equiv x(\color{#c00}1)^k\equiv x\ $ since $\,\color{#c00}{x^{46}\equiv 1}\,$ follows by Fermat's Little Theorem (note $\,x\not\equiv 0\,$ by $\,x^{15}\equiv 2).$

Conceptually: raise $\,x^{15} \equiv 2\pmod{47}$ to power $\,\dfrac{1}{15} \equiv m\pmod{46}\,$ to get $\, x \equiv 2^m\pmod{47}$

**Remark** $\ {\rm mod}\ 46\!:\ m\equiv \dfrac{1}{15}\equiv \dfrac{-45}{15}\equiv \color{#c0f}{-3}\equiv \color{#0a0}{43}.\ $ But $\,2^{\large\color{#c0d}{-3}}\equiv \dfrac{1}8\equiv\dfrac{48}8\equiv 6\pmod{47}$ computes easier than $\,2^{\large \color{#0a0}{43}}.$ This explains the algebra in Don Antonio's answer, i.e. it is equivalent to using this general method but with the least magnitude rep $\,1/15\equiv \color{#c0f}{-3}\,$ vs. $\,\color{#0a0}{43}\pmod{46}.\,$ Using least magnitude (a.k.a. balanced) reps is a standard optimization method in modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

My way isn't really different but we can start with Fermat's Little Theorem , following the hint by lab bhattacharjee.

$$x^{46} \ \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 47) $$

$$(x^{15})^3 \cdot x \ \equiv \ 1 \ (mod \ 47) $$

$$ 8x \ \equiv \ 1 \ (mod \ 47) $$

Now it's obvious x = 6